# WebSocket connection to 'wss://tm.filter:1508/' failed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

Поднял чистое приложение на Vue-cli 2.6 + установил несколько зависимостей в соответствии с нуждами, там ничего криминального, все супер известное.
Вот сама ошибка (с регулярной периодичностью сыпет в консоль):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в network - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Особо никакой информации нету..

Вот main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
// import axios from 'axios';
import App from './App.vue';

new Vue({
    
    
    render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="dashboard">
    </div>
</template>
```

а вот package.json

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "npm i && vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@factoringplus/pl-components-pack": "^1.11.9",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "element-ui": "^2.15.3",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
        "urlencode": "^1.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.11",
        "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
        "vuex": "^3.4.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^3.12.1",
        "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^5.0.2",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
        "husky": "^6.0.0",
        "lint-staged": "^11.1.2",
        "prettier": "^2.3.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
        "sass": "^1.32.4",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.1"
    }
}
```

Знаете может какая зависимость сыпет? Или где посмотреть? Или это нормальное поведение?
Заранее благодарю.
З.Ы. Если что - работать не мешает, просто глаза мозолит

Кликнул справа как посоветовал @PashaPash
Похоже на moment.js но тут особо не разберёшь(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно ткнуть в правую часть ошибки и глянуть кто запрос отправил

Comment: Добавил в вопрос инфу.

Comment: Удаление moment.js не решило проблему(

Comment: Это же ваш код - поставьте брекпойнт, посмотрите откуда вызывается. Что-то связанное в WhatsApp

Comment: не совсем так, это стандартный vue-cli, при запуске через serve- там уже минифицированный код, особой информации он не несёт.. :(

Comment: Подключите сорсмапы